# Run chrome in background while running audio

Tags: google-chrome, background-process

I have an audio clip playing on localhost:3000 on a node (js) server. I want this audio to keep playing even after i close the chrome tab. How can i go about this?

Comment: What kind of solution do you imagine? Do you think any browser will continue performing action associated to a closed tab?

Comment: as in i access localhost:3000 on chrome or firefox, click the play button to start audio and close the browser, but pressing the close button takes it to the background. so on screen you cant see that the browser is open.

Comment: Maybe the browser is still open, but you closed the tab so the actions associated to it are terminated. It would be a major issue if the browser allowed sites to continue performing actions after you closed their tabs/windows. Imagine what use malicious website could do with that.